# Release memory OpenCV , right memory allocation/deallocation ( management ) on OpenCV structures in function

Tags: c++, memory, opencv, memory-leaks, allocation

I am calling next function inside class inside thread in loop ( capturing frames from camera and then processing them ) :

```
CvRect ImageProcessor::detectFaceInImage(const IplImage *inputImg) //
{
    IplImage *detectImg;
    CvMemStorage* storage = 0;
    CvRect *rc = 0;
    CvRect rect;
    double count;
    CvSeq* rects = 0;
    int l,n;
    detection_time = (double)cvGetTickCount();
    detectImg = cvCloneImage(inputImg);
    if(fastDetectMode)
    {
        faceCascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad(
            faceCascadeFile[0].toAscii().data(), 
            0, 
            0, 
            0
        );

        if( !faceCascade )
        {
            QMessageBox mbox;
            mbox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
            mbox.setText("Can't load haar cascade face detector 0");
            mbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
            mbox.exec();

            if(detectImg)
                cvReleaseImage(&detectImg);

            return cvRect(-1,-1,-1,-1);
        }
        for(l=0;l<10;l++) //10 different search scale factors ( 10 )
        {
            storage = cvCreateMemStorage(1000000); //0

            rects = cvHaarDetectObjects(
                detectImg,
                (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)faceCascade, 
                storage, 
                search_scale_factor[l], 
                minNeighborhood[1],
                flags[0], 
                minFeatureSize[0]
            );

            if(rects->total>0)
            {
                for(n=0;n<rects->total;n++)
                {
                    rc = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( rects, n );
                    if((rc->height > 0.1*faceHeight) && (rc->width>0.1*faceWidth))
                    {
                        if(detectImg)
                            cvReleaseImage(&detectImg);

                        if(faceCascade)
                            cvFree(&faceCascade);

                        count = (double)cvGetTickCount();

                        detection_time = (double)((count - detection_time) / 
                            (double)cvGetTickFrequency())/1000000;

                        rect = *rc;
                        cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
                        return rect;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(storage)
                cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
        }

        cvFree(&faceCascade);
    }

    //nothing found:
    rect = cvRect(-1,-1,-1,-1);
    count = (double)cvGetTickCount();

    detection_time = (double)((count - detection_time) / 
        (double)cvGetTickFrequency())/1000000;

    if(detectImg)
        cvReleaseImage(&detectImg);

    return rect;
}
```

I am expecting each time I call that function all necessary memory for detecting desired face region ( rectangle cvRect) in the input image is allocated and deallocated after function return. But what is happening when I run it is that there is some memory leak in function , another words , the RAM ( PC physical memory ) is constantly growing up when I call the function in a loop.

faceCascade is ImageProcessor class member as well as another not declared in the function variables.
Does anybody see what is wrong with memory creation/release ( allocation/deallocation ) in the function?
Why memory leak.
Thank you very much in advance for your help.
Paul

Comment: The easiest way: use the correct OpenCV interface (assuming the question isn't tagged C++ by incident) to not break your head about memory management of OpenCV resources (at least most of the time).

Comment: I would second Christian's comment. Don't use the C interface, the memory management is a pain. Let the newer C++ `Mat` objects manage the memory for you! :) Or, create your own `IplImage` wrapper class that essentially automatically manages the memory for you. Seems like a waste of time though ;)

Comment: You can comment out part of the code and re-run the program to see if there is still any memory leaks. By repeating these steps, you will shorten the range of suspected code and finally pinpoint the problem!

Comment: Have you used a proper tool to detect the memory leak? Try valgrind.